John Lee introduction to complex manifolds problem 9-13.
Problem:
Suppose $T = V/\Lambda$ is a complex torus of dimension $n$. Define the dual torus to be the group $T^* = \text{Hom}(T, U(1))$ (the set of homomorphisms from $T$ to the circle group, which is a group under pointwise multiplication).
(a) Let $V^{*}$ denote the complex vector space of conjugate-linear functionals from $V$ to $\mathbb{C}$. Show there is a surjective group homomorphism $\Phi: V^* \to T^*$ that sends $f$ to the homomorphism $\Phi(f)(v) = e^{2\pi i \text{Im}(f(v))}$, and its kernel is the lattice
$
\Lambda^* = \{ f \in V^*: \text{Im}(f(v)) \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ for all } v \in \Lambda \}.
$
Conclude that $T^*$ also has the structure of a complex torus of dimension $n$, isomorphic to $V^*/\Lambda^*$.
(b) For a compact Kähler manifold $M$, show that $\text{Alb}(M)$ is holomorphically isomorphic to the dual torus of $\text{Pic}^0(M)$.

My Question:

How can $\Phi(f)$ be well-defined for an arbitrary conjugate-linear functional $f$? Doesn’t $f$ need to belong to $\Lambda^*$ for $\Phi(f)$ to be well-defined?

It it true that $T^{**}=T$? If it is then is it trivial?



In (a), he defined $V^*$ as the complex vector space of conjugate-linear functionals from $V$ to $C$

If f was in $Λ^$ then $Φ(f)$ would be well defined. But here he is saying that $Φ(f)$ is well defined for all $f$ in $V^$. Please read (a) carefully.

Got it. I agree with you that there is a problem. Writing $v$ forcan element of the torus is problematic indeed.

You're right -- unfortunately, there are several errors in the statement of that problem. I've posted a correction here.
As to your second question, yes, it is true that $T^{**}\cong T$. An easy way to prove this is to note that $\Lambda^{**}=\Lambda$ (under the natural identification of $V$ with the set of conjugate-linear functionals on $\overline V^*$).

is this a new book? i didn't see in your wikipedia page

@BCLC: yes, it was published earlier this year. Apparently Wikipedia hasn't caught up with it yet.

Thank you for your response, Prof. Lee. However, I still have a few questions.


How can we show that $\Phi$ is surjective? From what I understand, this would require sending the $2n$-many $\mathbb{R}$-linear elements in  $\Lambda$ to $\mathbb{C}$ in a $\mathbb{C}$-linear way, but how is this possible?


In a similar context as 1, how can $\Lambda^*$ contain $2n$-many $\mathbb{R}$-linear independent elements?


Where is the conjugate-linear condition used?



@PSC: These sound like new questions. Probably should start a new thread.
